# Nagios and ubuntu 16.04 run query on MSSQL

Tags: sql-server, ubuntu-16.04, nagios

I am trying to build a set of tests in a nagios install I have on ubuntu 16.04, that are based on the results of queries run against a MSSQL server else where on the network, at this time I struggling plugin that still has support.

Any suggestions of ways to do this would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

https://exchange.nagios.org/directory/Plugins/Databases/SQLServer/check_mssql/details

This plugin will do exactly what you want.

Download it and place the script in your plugin directory (usually `/usr/local/nagios/libexec`)

Make sure you have the proper dependencies installed. Ubuntu 16.04 should be:

```
sudo apt-get install php5-sybase freetds-common libsybdb5
```

And then set up your command definition:

```
define command{
    command_name   check_mssql_query
    command_line   $USER1$/check_mssql -H $HOSTADDRESS$ $ARG1$
}
```

Then add it as a service to whatever Host monitors the MSSQL server:

```
define service{
    host_name              mssql-server
    service_description    MSSQL Query 1
    use                    local-service
    check_command          check_mssql_query!--username USERNAME --password PASSWORD --port PORT --instance INSTANCE --database DATABASE --query QUERY
    register               1
}
```

I suggest reading through the help of the plugin itself with the command:

```
./check_mssql -h
```

It has a lot more helpful information. Good luck!

Comment: I have tried this Plugin in but it is dependencies are not available in ubuntu 16.04, I need to find a way to get them or another method to get the same results in to nagios